# "TLS configuration is invalid" when call "docker-compose build"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I trying to running the Docker on my Linux Ubuntu machine. After creating a docker-machine named clicc ("docker-machine create -d virtualbox clicc"), I ran the following code and got error messages.

```
XXX:~/dockerFile/clicc$ sudo docker-machine env clicc; eval $(sudo docker-machine env clicc)
sudo: unable to resolve host XXX
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/home/XXX/.docker/machine/machines/clicc"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="clicc"
# Run this command to configure your shell: 
# eval $(docker-machine env clicc)
sudo: unable to resolve host XXX
XXX:~/dockerFile/clicc$ docker-compose build
ERROR: TLS configuration is invalid - make sure your DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY and DOCKER_CERT_PATH are set correctly.
You might need to run `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"`
```

I reran "eval $(sudo docker-machine env clicc)", but still I got the same error message.

I would appreciate someone could help me figure out what the problem is.

Comment: what version of docker-compose are you using?

Comment: The latest one install through pip.

Comment: I just reinstalled everything and problem solved.

Comment: The question was already answered so we can remove.